# How to remove content before a pattern in xml using unix

Tags: shell-script, awk, sed, xml

```
Source file example:
<HDR></HDR><b></b><c></c>
```

(XML file created in a single line)

OR

```
Source file example:
<HDR>
</HDR>
<b>
</b>
<c>
</c>
```

I need to remove all the content of the file before `<b>` in both of the source format. 
I tried using the below method

```
sed 's/^.*b/b/'
```

But this is not replacing it. Please let me know if there is an alternative way.

Comment: Please be clearer as to what you want to accomplish and why. A little context might be useful in understanding your needs and helping you find a solution.

Comment: The XML is not well formed as there is no root tag around the whole document.

Comment: I have a header in the XML which needs to be replaced with different header

Comment: It seems then your problem is different from what you describe. Please add complete specifications of what you're trying to accomplish (replacing header tag?) in order to avoid the [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Answer (score 5):

Assuming your XML document is well formed, like

```
<document>
<HDR>
</HDR>
<b>
</b>
<c>
</c>
</document>
```

Then you may use [XMLStarlet](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/) to remove all `HDR` tags like so:

```
xmlstarlet ed -d '//HDR' file.xml >newfile.xml
```

To only remove the `HDR` tags that are immediately followed by a `b` tag:

```
xmlstarlet ed -d '//HDR[following-sibling::*[1][name() = "b"]]' file.xml >newfile.xml
```

---

XMLStarlet may also be used to modify the contents of tags:

```
$ xmlstarlet ed -u '//HDR[following-sibling::*[1][name() = "b"]]' -v 'New header value' file.xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<document>
  <HDR>New header value</HDR>
  <b/>
  <c/>
</document>

$ xmlstarlet ed -i '//HDR[following-sibling::*[1][name() = "b"]]' -t attr -n 'new_attribute' -v 'hello' file.xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<document>
  <HDR new_attribute="hello"/>
  <b/>
  <c/>
</document>
```

Comment: It has not been stressed enough that XML files should be treated as such and handled by dedicated tools, as opposed to be regarded as text files and messed with with the wrong tools.

Comment: This command is not  added to our version, we can't ask the admins to install it. Thanks !!

Answer (score 2):

**Question:**

> remove all contents of the file before `<b>`

**Answer:**

```
perl -0777 -lape 's/^.*<b>/<b>/s'
```

**Test run:**

```
==> in1.txt <==
<HDR></HDR><b></b><c></c>

==> in2.txt <==
<HDR>
</HDR>
<b>
</b>
<c>
</c>

$ perl -i -0777 -lape 's/^.*<b>/<b>/s' in{1,2}.txt

==> in1.txt <==
<b></b><c></c>

==> in2.txt <==
<b>
</b>
<c>
</c>
```

Comment: I tried this , It removed the every content after the <b> tag  as well, now there <b> tag alone in the new file

Comment: @user7952074 that means there's a `<b>` tag at the end of the file :-) Please follow @Kusalananda's advice and stick to well-formed XML and proper XML manipulation tools.

Answer (score 1):

**Type 1**:

```
 echo "<HDR></HDR><b></b><c></c>" | sed 's/^.*<b>/<b>/' 
 <b></b><c></c>
```

- will replace everything up to `<b>` with `<b>`

**Type 2**:

```
sed  -n '/<b>/,$p' file
<b>
</b>
<c>
</c>
```

- will print the first occurrence of `<b>` to end of the file ($).